# Context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri) throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-intent, inputstream, android-contentresolver

I'm using this intent for letting user to choose files

```
val fileChooser = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
fileChooser.type = "*/*"
fileChooser.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
fileChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true)
fileChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
startActivityForResult(fileChooser, FILE_REQUEST_CODE)
```

And in `onActivityResult`

```
val uri: Uri? = data.data
context?.contentResolver?.openInputStream(uri)
```

in this line it's throwing exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)

It's throwing this exception only in Android 5 devices & only for docx,xlsx,mp3 file types other images & video files are working fine with the same code

This is sample uri which I'm getting from intent: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/30159

Comment: `com.android.providers.downloads.documents` Please select file not from Downloads but from internal storage so provider authority becomes `com.android.externalstorage.documents`

Comment: It's on user choice, user can select file from any location

Comment: Of course. So now for a test you will choose like i proposed. Select the same file.